# Combox DataBinding

Tags: data-binding, combobox

I have trouble binding a Class to a combobox

This is my code (that is working) :

```
public partial class NameView : UserControl
{
    public NameView(NameViewModel nameViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = nameViewModel.NameList;
    }
 }
```

And the XAML :

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Width="220" Height="35"
             ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             SelectedIndex="0">
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

When I bind the datacontext to the NameList (List of NameModels) like in the example, the combobox is populated with the Name property of the NameModel.

But I want to bind the datacontext to the whole NameViewModel like this :

```
public partial class NameView : UserControl
{
public NameView(NameViewModel nameViewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = nameViewModel;
        //this.DataContext = nameViewModel.NameList;
    }
}
```

And bind the Combobox to the NameList.
but this is not working

```
    <Grid>
    <ComboBox Width="220" Height="35"
             //ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding NameList}"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             SelectedIndex="0">
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

Why is that ?

Kind regards

Comment: I have found the problem.
The NameList was a field instead of a property